# R: something weird with as.POSIXct()

Tags: r, date

Can anyone explain me what happens here?

```
> as.POSIXct(paste("20140329", "02:00:00"), format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2014-03-29 02:00:00 CET"
> as.POSIXct(paste("20140330", "01:59:59"), format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2014-03-30 01:59:59 CET"
> as.POSIXct(paste("20140330", "02:00:00"), format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] NA
```

Comment: You haven't provided `sessionInfo()`, so this is just a guess, but it's probably because that is the time daylight saving time occurs in your timezone. Thus 2am does not exist on that date.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: If you make it an answer, I'll accept it!